# Best way to do plus or minus

Tags: swift

Is there a native or simpler way to do plus or minus when comparing two double values. Right now I have done two comparisons like this but I feel like there should be a cleaner way to do this. We are doing a lot of these comparisons in our app so I would prefer to use the simplest and cleanest function for this.

```
let y: Double = 5 // main value
let x: Double = 6 // value that we are comparing y to
if x > y + 2 || x > y - 2 {
    //Do something
}
```

I am basically looking to check if x (in this case 6) is between 3 (5-2) and 7 (5+2). I want to do something if it is between the two value and do something else if it is not.

If possible, I want to do it by using the value of 2 opposed to explicitly writing out 3 and 7.

Comment: I just changed them to doubles

Comment: Your code doesn't check that the value is within a range, it checks that x is greater than y - 2. if `x > y + 2`, then `x > y - 2` is necessarily true.

Answer (score 3):

To check whether `x` is within `2` of `y`:

```
if abs(x - y) < 2 {
    ...
}
```

It's simple enough to understand alone, I think, but for the sake of completeness:

- this moves the test to being around 0. If `x` is exactly equal to `y` then `x - y` is `0`. If `x` is two less than `y` then `x - y` is `-2`. If it is two greater than `x - y` is `2`. If it is anywhere between then it is somewhere in the middle. So the interesting range is `(-2, 2)`;
- applying an `abs` both gives an interesting range of `[0, 2)` and guarantees no outcome is below `0`;
- therefore a comparison only to the upper end of the range is sufficient.

Comment: Depends on how you read the question. The code posted uses a hard `>`, not a `>=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matching:

```
if (y-2)...(y+2) ~= x {
    // your code in case the value is within the range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use it may be helpful to check to see if X is in a set of numbers.